# Найти глубину рекурсии

Tags: pascal, delphi-7, pascalabc.net

Найти глубину рекурсии в данной программе

```
program with_rec_func;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
SysUtils;

var n:integer;

function X(i:integer):integer;
begin
  if i<3 then X:=-3
  else X:=X(i-1)+X(i-2)+4;
X:= Result;
end;

begin
  n:=0;
  repeat
    inc(n);
  until X(n)>0;
  writeln(' Least element with a plus sign X(n) = ',X(n));
  writeln(' Its number n = ',n);
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Нарисуйте на бумаге дерево вызовов, увидите, какой высоты оно достигает в зависимости от n.

Потом проверьте, добавив к функции параметр level, передавайте его увеличенным на 1 при каждом рекурсивном вызове, выведите в момент остановки рекурсии.

И уберите это: `X:= Result;`

Comment: Я не понимаю как к конкретно этой программе рисовать дерево, n изменяется по возрастанию и меня это вводит в заблуждение, если б наоборот я бы нарисовала

Comment: В функции аргумент не возрастает.

Comment: Я просто смотрю работу стека, для меня не понятно, что откуда идёт, не представляю как к конкретно этой программе нарисовать дерево

Comment: Берёте, например, функцию с аргументом 6 и рисуете две ветки рекурс. вызовов - с аргументом 5 и с аргументом 4, для каждой ветки продолжаете то же самое.

Comment: Да, я это понимаю, но здесь для меня не ясно, сначала вызывается х(1), потом х(2), х(3) от которого уже идут 2 ветки х(2) и х(1), затем уже х(4), от которого - х(3), от которого в свою очередь х(2) и х(1), и х(2), затем х(5) и там тоже самое, они не вызываются последовательно друг за другом, как это было бы если бы сразу вызывалось х(5), где все ясно все ветки друг за другом, а как быть в этой программе, они по идее отдельно будут располагаться не в одном дерево, извините, может я чего-то недопонимаю))

Comment: Не в одном. Это набор деревьев, вам нужно самое высокое. Ввиду монотонности изменения аргументов это просто последний вызов из цикла.

Comment: То есть, если мне надо отобразить работу рекурсии в данной программе по такому принципу https://yandex.by/images/search?text=сущность%20рекурсии%20схема&pos=2&img_url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn2.arhivurokov.ru%2FviewImage.php%3Fimage%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.tvd-home.ru%2Fimages%2Frecursion%2Fr1.gif&rpt=simage, то брать только последний вызов? Просто если количество блоков соответствует количеству вызовов, то наглядности глубины рекурсии не будет

Comment: Если дерево будет горизонтально, то нужно, получается, сделать несколько строк, в каждой дерево длиннее и длиннее